# C# Make async http requests within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel.foreach

I need to make multiple webrequests where URIs are in a DataTable. Earlier I had the below code. But I realized this makes synchronous calls as ***await*** would wait till GET/POST call is complete and response is processed then it proceeds to next iteration.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    activeTasks.Add(SendRequestAsync(dr));
    Task.WhenAll(activeTasks).Wait();
}

private async Task<string> SendRequestAsync(DataRow dr)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string reqMethod = (dr["RequestMethod"] != null && dr["RequestMethod"].ToString() != "") ? dr["RequestMethod"].ToString() : "GET";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(dr["URL"].ToString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        string reqContentType = (dr["RequestContentType"] != null && dr["RequestContentType"].ToString() != "") ? dr["RequestContentType"].ToString() : "text/xml";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(reqContentType));

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        try
        {
            if (reqMethod == "GET")
                response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri);
            else
                response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri, null);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseText;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "-1";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I came across **Parallel** feature and used **Parallel.ForEach** instead. Like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(rows, dr =>
{
    activeTasks.Add(SendRequestAsync(dr));
    Task.WhenAll(activeTasks).Wait();
});
```

This works fine, parallelism is achieved, requests are asynchronous and it completes within fraction of a time as compared to earlier solution. 
But the problem is it is not reliable - at times I get errors like

- System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array
- System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Is there anyway we can achieve http async calls within a foreach?

Comment: I wouldn't use the `Parallel.ForEach` for this. Really you just want to move your `Task.WhenAll` outside of the loop that you are adding tasks to your task list in.

Comment: When using parallel foreach you want to make sure you use threadsafe collections from the concurrent collections namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: As an aside, if you do decide to make your calls concurrently, you may need to increase the timeout on each call, as you may have a request blocked by the maximum number of simultaneous sockets being open in some environments.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient): *HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads.*

Comment: Thanks all for your responses, I upvoted everyone :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Johnathon_Chase said, just move your `WhenAll()` call outside of the loop:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    activeTasks.Add(SendRequestAsync(dr));
}
Task.WhenAll(activeTasks).Wait();
```

The `for` loop populates the collection, and then `Task.WhenAll()` blocks while the requests complete.

Answer (score 4):

`Parallel.ForEach` is for CPU-intensive operations and is not designed for I/O-intensive operations or for async.

You can `await` inside of a `foreach` loop just fine. The method containing your loop needs to be async itself, though.